# React Ionic Rtl / Right To Left

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, right-to-left

Hello there I was Surfing the web for a while and couldn't find an answer to how to implement RTL to react-ionic project I am about to start...
i was looking at some general discussion saying that you can add a mixin to a sass file like
[this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/rtl-support/):

```
$app-direction: rtl // RTL only apps
```

i dont understand if this only apply to angular ionic project or m i missing somthing?

my global `.scss` file (no wrappers around it) :

```
$app-direction: rtl;
```